# Qt4: Scale invariant qgraphicsitem outlines

Tags: qt, qt4, qgraphicsview

I am drawing some polygons using the Qt4 GraphicsView framework, and I allow the user to zoom in and out of the drawing. I would like the polygons to get larger and smaller as the user changes zoom levels (scale) in the view, but is there a way to make the outline thickness always remain the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes I guess there is at least this possibility :

You can call

```
void QPen::setCosmetic ( bool cosmetic )
```

with TRUE value on the pen using to draw the
polygon. This property allows to keep constant the width regardless of any transformations applied on QPainter !

Hope it helps !